# R tidy row means from subset of columns

Tags: r, row, tidyverse

I would like to compute summary variables from multiple columns in a data frame. This is possible when typing out all the row names, but I would like to use starts_with() and similar functions. I.e.

```
df <- data.frame(A1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                 A2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                 A3 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                 B1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                 B2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1))
```

What works:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(A = (A1 + A2 + A3)/3)
df %>% mutate(A = rowMeans(select(., A1:A3)))
```

However, the former gets annoying when summarising many variables, while the latter gets incredibly slow very quickly when summarising many rows. I suspect there must be a faster solution.

What does not work:

```
df %>% mutate(A = mean(A1:A3))
df %>% group_by(row_number()) %>% mutate(A = mean(A1:A3))
df %>% group_by(row_number()) %>% mutate(A = mean(starts_with("A")))
```

So my question is: Is there a way to use mean() etc. within mutate() to compute row means, ideally without having to spell out every single variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my previous version I thought that `rowMeans` is the concern, but actually what is slowing down the calculation is the usage of `select` - better just stick with the `grep` family:

```
df %>% mutate(A = rowMeans(.[, grepl("^A", names(.))]))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use in your `select` function the function `starts_with`:

```
df %>% mutate(A = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("A"))))
```

If you search the help for `select_helpers` you find several more.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is essentially my second 'what works' example, except using starts_with(). Unfortunately, this gets very slow very quickly, so I was hoping there would be a faster solution.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the performance part!

Answer (score 4):

Base R is the fastest in my tests.
I will use a bigger dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)

n <- 1e4
df <- data.frame(A1 = rnorm(n, 0, 1),
                 A2 = rnorm(n, 0, 1),
                 A3 = rnorm(n, 0, 1),
                 B1 = rnorm(n, 0, 1),
                 B2 = rnorm(n, 0, 1))

mb <- microbenchmark(
  m1 = df %>% mutate(A = (A1 + A2 + A3)/3),
  m2 = df %>% mutate(A = rowMeans(select(., A1:A3))),
  m3 = df %>% mutate(A = reduce(.[, grepl("^A", names(.))], `+`) / ncol(.[, grepl("^A", names(.))])),
  m4 = rowMeans(df[, grep("^A", names(df))]),
  m5 = df[, grep("^A", names(df))] %>% rowMeans()
)

mb

autoplot(mb)
```

The purely base R way is faster, followed by the base R subsetting/`dplyr` pipe.

Comment: Nice benchmark! Doesn't impact the performance that much, but should be noted that for the same output `%>% cbind(df, A = .)` (or something similar) would need to be added to `m4` and `m5`.

Comment: @arg0naut Or `%>% bind_cols(df, A = .)`, to use a `dplyr` function.